# What direction is aerodynamic lift in?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics, aircraft, lift

So I was researching about aerodynamic lift, in all the research I read it says lift is perpendicular to the flow direction. But in 3d space there isn't only one perpendicular vector to a given vector.

Reason why im asking is because, the rudder of the airplane moves the airplane by lift force. (Lift force is produced sideways in a rudder), in contrast to airplanes which produce lift upwards.

How can I determine which direction lift will be?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, lift occurs perpendicular to a plane (two-dimensional surface) over which the airflow occurs.  In this case, there is only one perpendicular direction to the surface of a plane.  This is the case for both the wing of an aircraft and the rudder.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The simplest counterexample is the flat plate at an angle of attack, in which the lift is vertical (assuming a horizontal onset flow), not normal to the surface of the plate. You are not accounting for the so-called "leading-edge suction."

Comment: So, I understand one of the answers says the reason why rudders work is because of sideways lift, but redirecting the flow of air (Isn't that the same principle as lift?). Or do rudders work because of a different principle

@D.Halsey

Answer (score 1):

Lift is perpendicular to both the air flow and the surface of the airfoil.

A rudder doesn't work by creating aerodynamic lift but by creating a force from redirecting the flow of air.

(Lift is created by one side of a foil being more convex than the other. The more convex side causes a faster flow of air, reducing the pressure it exerts on the foil. A rudder directly deflects a portion of the air, resulting in an uneven pressure distribution. A rudder causes much greater drag per force/lift than an airfoil.)

Comment: But what vector would be representing the surface of the airfoil?

Comment: Convexity of the foil is not necessary for creating lift. A simple flat plate has no curvature, but can still be lifting.

Comment: @D.Halsey I was trying to hint at Bernoulli's principle.